RabbitMQ JMS and MessageDriven bean through TomEE
I'm trying to implement a Jakarta application with JMS runnning in TomEE 9.1.3 and a RabbitMQ 3.10.8.
I can send and receive messages using injected QueueConnectionFactory and Queue resources.
Here the resources declaration:
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" reloadable="true">
    <Resource name="jms/RMQConnectionFactory"
              type="jakarta.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"
              factory="com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQObjectFactory"/>
    <Resource name="jms/RMQQueue"
              type="jakarta.jms.Queue"
              factory="com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQObjectFactory"
              destinationName="dsn-api"/>
</Context>

Here the methods for sending and receiving messages :
public class JMSTest {
    @Resource(name = "jms/RMQConnectionFactory")
    private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(name = "jms/RMQQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    public void send() {
        try (var context = connectionFactory.createContext()) {
            var producer = context.createProducer();
            var message = context.createTextMessage("Hello world!");
            producer.send(queue, message);
        }
    }

    public String receive() throws JMSException {
        try (var context = connectionFactory.createContext()) {
            var consumer = context.createConsumer(queue);
            var message = consumer.receive();
            System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", message.getJMSMessageID(), message.getBody(String.class));
        }
    }
}

I'd like to use a Message Driven Bean to handle messages but nothing happens while it is well deployed:
20-Dec-2024 15:44:18.452 INFOS [main] org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments.deploy Auto-deploying ejb MyMessageListener: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=DsnMessageListener)

Here the MDB :
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:comp/env/jms/RMQConnectionFactor"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:comp/env/jms/RMQQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "jakarta.jms.Queue")
})
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println(message.getBody(String.class));
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Is that possible or am I doing it wrong?

can you give some insight about your openejb.xml

I did not edit the openejb.xml so it should be at it initial state. (Sorry I won't be at the office until Thursday)
